# MultiMap Data Structure for constant time ranking

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

let me just say this is a HW project from UC Berkeley, so If you could give me a hint instead of the solution, It'd be great.

The problem is to create a data structure called "YearlyRecord" that maps a word to the number of times it is encountered in an ngram file. Here are the restrictions.

- getting the count must be *O(1)*
- getting the number of mappings must be *O(1)*
- "put" must be on average *O(log n)*
- getting the "rank" must be *O(1)*
- counts, which provides a data structure of all of counts in increasing order
- words, which provides a data structure of all words, in the order of counts

Note: "rank" is a function that takes a word and tells me its rank (e.g. `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`), which is based on the number of occurrences we have of it.

My solutions so far:

- Hashmap (word -> count) provides *O(1)* getCount operation and
  *O(1)* size operation
- make a private inner class that implements Comparator which compares based on the number of occurrences in the hashmap. Then use
  this comparator as input to a TreeSet of the words. This provides the
  "words" collection, which we can return in *O(1)* time.
- Make another TreeSet of the counts. This provides an *O(1)* return of the counts in increasing order.
- rank: Here is where I am stuck. It is clear that rank should be a map as well. I have the words in the TreeSet in increasing order of rank, but no indices to map to.

Comment: I don't see myself retrieving anything from it. "words" and "counts" gets the whole collection, that is O(1) because I just return the whole set. 
As far as O(lgn) "put," that is perfectly ok, I am actually constrained by a O(lgn) "put" on YearlyRecord

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean. But you were not actually constrained on the performance of `counts` and `words`, were you?

Comment: no, the only constraints were on count, size, rank. The explicit ones at least. Making "counts" and "words" constant was my initiative.

Comment: just as a reminder, the retrieval of the count of a word is done through the hashmap

Comment: Yes, but when you return such data structures, you should return a *copy* of your internal structure, or whoever uses the reference can change it, and then you will give a bad data structure next time.

Comment: yea I know returning a view is a problem. I wanted to take this one step at a time, finish the rank problem, have it run as fast as I can, then go back and deal with the view. At this point, we can safely assume nobody is going to mess with the view

Comment: How do we determine the rank of a word if several words have the same number of occurrences?

Comment: We return any one of them, so say the first one in a list

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design a system to keep top k frequent words real time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692624/design-a-system-to-keep-top-k-frequent-words-real-time)

Comment: @SergeyKojoian: The answer to the linked question provides the outline of an algorithm which should help solve your problem.